# Possible to select multiple tiles (pictureboxes)

Tags: vb.net, picturebox, bots

Hey so I'm trying to create this little bot.. However I got this code from a friend, it's a small 5x5 tiles, I can only select one tile with this and it will only use the one tile. I would like to be able to select multiple tiles and then the bot will also use the multiple tiles registered.

Tiles code is

```
Public Class Tiles
Private _activeTile As Integer = 0
Public ReadOnly Property activeTile As Integer
    Get
        Return _activeTile
    End Get
End Property
Private Sub PictureBox_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click, PictureBox2.Click, PictureBox3.Click, PictureBox4.Click, PictureBox5.Click, PictureBox6.Click, PictureBox7.Click, PictureBox8.Click, PictureBox9.Click, PictureBox10.Click, PictureBox11.Click, PictureBox12.Click, PictureBox13.Click, PictureBox14.Click, PictureBox15.Click, PictureBox16.Click, PictureBox17.Click, PictureBox18.Click, PictureBox19.Click, PictureBox20.Click, PictureBox21.Click, PictureBox22.Click, PictureBox23.Click, PictureBox24.Click, PictureBox25.Click
    Dim p As PictureBox = TryCast(sender, PictureBox)
    Dim id As Integer = CInt(p.Name.Split("x")(1))
    If p.BorderStyle = Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.Fixed3D Then
        p.BorderStyle = Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None
        p.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(&HDD, &HDD, &HDD)
        _activeTile = 0
    Else
        resetActiveTile()
        p.BorderStyle = Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.Fixed3D
        p.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(&HA9, &HA9, &HA9)
        _activeTile = id
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub resetActiveTile()
    For Each c As Control In Me.Controls
        If c.Name.StartsWith("Pic") Then
            Dim p As PictureBox = TryCast(c, PictureBox)
            Dim id As Integer = CInt(p.Name.Split("x")(1))
            p.BorderStyle = Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None
            p.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(&HDD, &HDD, &HDD)
            _activeTile = 0
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Tiles_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    PictureBox1.BorderStyle = Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.Fixed3D
    PictureBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(&HA9, &HA9, &HA9)
    _activeTile = 1
End Sub
```

End Class

And here is the function where the active tile get used

```
    Private Sub guess()
    Try
        If Tiles1.activeTile = 0 Then
            BackgroundWorker1.CancelAsync()
            MsgBox("Please select a tile!")
        Else
            s.Guess(currGame, Tiles1.activeTile)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        log(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Thanks a ton! :)